# Performance issues with large datasets

Tags: resolvejs

Is there any way of filtering the events in a projection associated with a read model by the `aggregateId`?

In the tests carried out we always receive *all* registered events. Is it possible to apply filters in a previous stage?

We have 100,000 `aggregateId` and each `id` has associated 15,000 `events`. Unable to filter by `aggregateId`, our projections have to iterate over *all* `events`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you building a read model for a single aggregate? Read model is essentially a read database for a whole app, so it supposed to be persistent. In your case it may take a while to build at first time, but then it will only  consume new events.

Comment: We don't know what is the best approach in order to achieve our requirements. We try retrieve state using ViewModel too (applying aggregateId filter), but it seems its performance is very low when event records are growing. Example, for 15.000 events ViewModel projection takes 50 seconds... Our system will have a lot of more events in real world... We know subsequents request increase a lot performance but we are concern about the first request response times when app is initialize...

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm writing a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have 100.000 aggregates with 15.000 events each.

You can use [ReadModel or ViewModel](https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/read-side):

**Read Model**:

Read model can be seen as a read database for your app. So if you want to store some data about each aggregate, you should insert/update row or entry in some table for each aggregate, see [Hacker News example read model code](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/examples/hacker-news/common/read-models/hacker-news.projection.js#L29-L106).

It is important to understand that resolve read models are built on demand - on the first query. If you have a lot of events, it may take some time.

Another thing to consider - a newly created resolve app is configured to use in-memory database for read models, so on each app start you will have it rebuilt.

If you have a lot of events, and don't want to wait to wait for read models to build each time you start the app, you have to configure a real database storage for your read models.

Configiuring adapters is not well documented, [we'll fix this](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/issues/968). Here is what you need to write in the relevant config file for mongoDB:

```
readModelAdapters: [
  {
    name: 'default',
    module: 'resolve-readmodel-mongo',
    options: {
      url: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MyDatabaseName',
    }
  }
]
```

Since you have a database engine, you can use it for an event store too:

```
storageAdapter: {
  module: 'resolve-storage-mongo',
  options: {
    url: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MyDatabaseName',
    collectionName: 'Events'
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**
ViewModel is built on the fly during the query. It does not require a storage, but it reads all events for the given `aggregateId`.

reSolve view models are using snapshots. So if you have 15.000 events for a give aggregate, then on the first request all those events will be applied to calculate a vies state for the first time. After this, this state will be saved, and all subsequent requests will read a snapshot and all later events. By default snapshot is done per 100 events. So on the second query reSolve would read a snapshot for this view model, and apply not more than 100 events to it.

Again, keep in mind, that if you want snapshot storage to be persistent, you should configure a snapshot adapter:

```
snapshotAdapter: {
  module: 'resolve-snapshot-lite',
  options: {
    pathToFile: 'path/to/file',
    bucketSize: 100
  }
}
```

ViewModel has one more benefit - if you use resolve-redux middleware on the client, it will be kept up-to-date there, reactively applying events that app is receiving via websockets.

Comment: Thank you!
In our case, we will have the need to invalidate those caches frequently. The Read Model option is discarded for that reason.
If you have 1 aggregate with 15,000 events, generating the state is much faster with Read Model than with View Model, but if we have 100,000 aggregates with 15,000 events each, the Read Model is not an option either.
We are not going to use the resolve-redux middleware on the client.
Why is the generation of the state with the View Model much slower than with the Read Model? Can we configure the Read Model so that it only reads a given aggregate?

Comment: I think I don't understand your scenario - why would you want to invalidate read models frequently? 
Can you share a sample project and some test data illustrating your issues?

Comment: We need to invalidate the state because the user can request to be placed at any point in the timeline and that forces us to recalculate the state.

Comment: I'm afraid we are talking about rather special use case. Usually event sourced system looks like any other systems, read models are built during application initialization, and then just kept up-to-date by current stream of events.

In your case solution would be to add this temporal aspect to your read model. On every event that chages the aggregate state you can store this version of aggregate state with a timestamp - something like this.

Comment: In short - your read model should contain all answers on the questions it is asked. It should not be rebuilt on query.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much!